# How do I store a binary into an array and put it into different labels (compiling program)?

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I have a compiling program, but I'm having two minor issues. The program converts hexdecimal to decimal and binary and presents it in this cute little GUI.

Problem:

I want to put the binary into an array and then transmit it between 5 little box windows in a row. The code to convert is there, but I don't know how split it up.

Here's my driver:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class HBDconverter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Hexadecimal to Binary and Decimal #suchamaze");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    frame.getContentPane().add(new HBDconverterpanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Here's where all the more fun code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HBDconverterpanel extends JPanel {


     private JTextField hexString = new JTextField();
     private JLabel decimalNumber = new JLabel();
     private JLabel binaryNumber = new JLabel();


                public HBDconverterpanel() {

              JLabel programname = new JLabel("HBD Converter");
                 setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
                 setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

                 hexString.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        converttehInput();
                                                             }  
                                                            });

              JPanel panelName = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
              panelName.add(programname);
              panelName.add(hexString);
              add(panelName, BorderLayout.NORTH);

              JPanel binaryPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 6));
              binaryPanel.add(new JLabel("Binary"));
                  binaryPanel.add(binaryNumber);
              add(binaryPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JPanel decimalPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            decimalPanel.add(new JLabel("Decimal"));
            decimalPanel.add(decimalNumber);
            add(decimalPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
//This take the integer Input (really hex) and converts for the GUIs above
                       private void converttehInput() {
 //wow
                         {
                             Integer input = Integer.valueOf(hexString.getText(), 16);
                             decimalNumber.setText(String.valueOf(input));
                             binaryNumber.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(input));
                        }    

 }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have more of those than you expect.
I guess you used some code-generator/GUI builder,
and you didn't check what it generated for you.
You should review and clean up what's not needed.

```
          binaryLabel = new JLabel ("-");
        binaryLabel2 = new JLabel("-");
        binaryLabel3 = new JLabel("-");
        binaryLabel4 = new JLabel("-");
        binaryLabel5 = new JLabel("-");    
        binaryPanel.add(binaryLabel);
        binaryPanel.add(binaryLabel2);
        binaryPanel.add(binaryLabel3);
        binaryPanel.add(binaryLabel4);
        binaryPanel.add(binaryLabel5);
        binaryPanel.add(binaryLabel5);
```

Try this.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class HBDconverterpanel extends JPanel {

        private JTextField hexString = new JTextField();
        private JLabel decimalLabel, binaryLabel;
        private JLabel decimalNumber = new JLabel();
        private JLabel binaryNumber = new JLabel();

        public HBDconverterpanel() {

            JLabel programname = new JLabel("HBD Converter");
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

            hexString.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    converttehInput();
                }
            });

            JPanel panelName = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
            panelName.add(programname);
            panelName.add(hexString);
            add(panelName, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel binaryPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 6));
            binaryPanel.add(new JLabel("Binary"));
            binaryLabel = new JLabel("-");
            binaryPanel.add(binaryLabel);
            binaryPanel.add(binaryNumber);
            add(binaryPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JPanel decimalPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            decimalPanel.add(new JLabel("Decimal"));
            decimalLabel = new JLabel("-");
            decimalPanel.add(decimalLabel);
            decimalPanel.add(decimalNumber);
            add(decimalPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }

        // This take the integer Input (really hex) and converts for the GUIs above
        private void converttehInput() {
            // wow
            {
                Integer input = Integer.valueOf(hexString.getText(), 16);
                decimalNumber.setText(String.valueOf(input));
                binaryNumber.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(input));
            }

        }
    }
```

You should get this.

[image]

Comment: No, I wrote this on jGrasp. I don't like bulky IDES. Oh I see, I added the same one twice. Whoops.

Comment: Wait, it's still giving me two for decimalLabel. Why?

Comment: @munchschair One for decimal, one for binary. I thought that's what you wanted.

Comment: `JPanel decimalPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
 decimalPanel.add(new JLabel("Decimal"));
 decimalLabel = new JLabel("-");
 decimalPanel.add(decimalLabel);
 decimalPanel.add(decimalNumber);
 add(decimalPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` This code I mean. When I run it, I get two "-" "-" to the right of "Decimal". Then one of outputs the decimal, but one is just there.

Comment: @munchschair Just run what I put in my answer. I don't see two there.

Comment: Did you put in a hexdecimal and press enter?

Comment: Eh, I'm just going to take these labels out

Comment: @munchschair Maybe your *.class files are not rebuilt properly. Try creating a new project in jGrasp and copying the code from here.

Comment: I took it out, I like it this way better now. Now it's a question of getting binary into different windows.